# Are edge relations always directed? Can undirected graphs have edge relations?

Tags: graph-theory

I have been unable to find a definition for an edge relation in a graph. I would be grateful if you could link me to an official definition for an edge relation in a graph that could answer the questions in the title.

If a graph has edge relations, does that imply that the graph is directed?

EDIT: My friend argues that since one-way edge relations exist (such as "less than"), graphs that contain edge relations are all directed. Is he correct?

Comment: Do you mean that if you have a relation over a set then you can express it as a directed graph? where aRb if and only if the edge (a,b) is part of E in the digraph?

Comment: I mean that if you define a graph, and say that the graph has edge relations, then does that imply that the graph is directed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a directed graph a is related to b means that the edge going from a to b exists. So you can transform you directed graph to a relation over the set $V$ (of vertices).

In the undirected graph situation we get a relation that is symmetric that is whenever we have $aRb$ we must also have $bRa$.

Comment: If he doesn't specify whether if the relation is symmetric or not, then does that imply that the graph is directed?

Comment: It really depends in the context, I wouyld ask just to be sure. Is he talking about digraphs or normal graphs?

Comment: I think it's a digraph because he writes from $X$ to $Y$ of course this is purely speculative. But I think the fact he says from one to another means it is directed. Otherwise most people would just write between x and y.

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll ask him.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Given an undirected graph, there is nothing to stop you from considering the relation $R$ on its vertex set such that $a\mathrel R b$ exactly if $a$ and $b$ are connected by an edge.

Conversely, whenever you have a symmetric irreflexive relation on some set $X$, it determines an undirected graph in this way.

"Edge relation" seems to be an excellent name for this sort of thing. There is no authority that determines "official" meanings for such terms, but the chance that you will be understood if you call it "the edge relation of the graph" or something like that approaches certainty, if your audience would be able to understand what you're saying at all.

Comment: So if you don't specify whether if the relation is symmetric or not, the graph could be directed OR undirected?

Comment: @user2108462: Yes, I don't think there's a clear signal either way. To some people "graph" without further specification implies a directed graph, to others an undirected graph. You can speak about the edge set as a relation in either case, so that doesn't help disambiguate.